# sidebar menu fragment not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

This code works fine but when I create a logout button in the sidebar menu in fragement, it stops working and the app crashes immediately:

```
package com.example.bulksms;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "ShowToast" })
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText Username;
    EditText Password;
    String line=null;
    // ProgressDialog 
     ProgressDialog progress;
    //ProgressDialog progress;
    // flag for Internet connection status
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    //session 
    SessionManager session;
    // Connection detector class
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    // 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // creating connection detector class instance
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        // get Internet status
        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

        //if TheradPolicy When app crash automatically.
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        //Array List For Branch Showing 
         try {
                if (isInternetPresent)
                {
                     // Session manager
                   session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
                   if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
                        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                         finish();
                    }
                   else{
                     Showing_branch();
                   }
                 }
                else
                {
                     // Internet connection is not present
                    // Ask user to connect to Internet
                   showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "No Internet Connection","You don't have internet connection.", false);
                }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error In Showing Branch", e.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Get Activity Main Data.
        Button submit;
        Username    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        Password    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        submit      = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitbtn);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Spinner Branch_Name = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.simple_spinner_item);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Select value:"+Branch_Name.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(Branch_Name.getSelectedItem().toString()=="")
                {
                     TextView tvInvisibleError = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInvisibleError);
                     tvInvisibleError.setError( "Select Branch name!" );
                     tvInvisibleError.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else if(Username.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                    {
                        Username.setError( "Username name is required!" );
                        Username.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        Username.setHint("Enter UserName!");
                    }
                    else if(Password.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                    {
                        Password.setError( "Password is required!" );
                        Password.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        Password.setHint( "Enter Password !" );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try {
                            Login(Username.getText().toString().trim(),Password.getText().toString().trim(),Branch_Name.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Function to Showing Branch List
     *  using This Function get Branch List form SERVER.
     * */

    void Showing_branch() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
        //
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading",
                  "Loading..", true);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run()
                  {
                    // do the thing that takes a long time

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run()
                      {
                        //progress.dismiss();
                      }
                    });
                  }
                }).start();

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.simple_spinner_item);

        ArrayList<String> options=new ArrayList<String>();

        options.add("");
        //options.add("option 3");
        //Get Server Value
        HttpClient httpclient   = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost       = new HttpPost("http://ayattechnologies.com/demo/sentsms/getNumber.php?Getdata=true");
        HttpResponse response   = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity       = response.getEntity();
        InputStream InputIs      = entity.getContent();
        //
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(InputIs,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
                InputIs.close();
                String result = sb.toString();
            //Get The json Data 
            JSONArray aJson = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0; i<aJson.length(); i++) 
            {
                JSONObject branchlist    = aJson.getJSONObject(i);
                String branch_id         = branchlist.getString("phoneNumber");
                options.add(branch_id);
            }

            //
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,options);
           adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
           mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
           progress.dismiss();
    }

    /**
     * Function to Login User
     * @param:Username
     * @param:Password
     * @param:BranchName
     * */

    public void Login(String Username, String Password,String branchName) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Login",
                  "Loading..", true);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run()
                  {
                    // do the thing that takes a long time
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run()
                      {
                        //progress.dismiss();
                      }
                    });
                  }
                }).start();

        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Username:"+Username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Creating HTTP client
         HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Creating HTTP Post
         HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://ayattechnologies.com/demo/sentsms/login.php");
         List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",Username ));
         nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",Password ));
         nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("branch",branchName ));
         httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
         HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
         Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());

         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         InputStream Is_response = entity.getContent();

         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(Is_response,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                     sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    Is_response.close();
                    String result    = sb.toString();
                    JSONArray aJson  = new JSONArray(result);
                    String responsedString = null;
                    for(int i=0; i<aJson.length(); i++) 
                    {
                      JSONObject json  = aJson.getJSONObject(i);
                      responsedString = json.getString("Success");
                    }
                    Log.d("Http Response:", responsedString);

                    //dismiss progressbar

                    if(responsedString.equals("Success"))
                    {

                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "responseData:"+responsedString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     //progress.dismiss();
                    // Create login session
                    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
                    session.setLogin(true);
                    session.setusename(Username);
                     //
                     Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Home.class);
                     i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                     startActivity(i);
                     finish();
                    }
                    else{
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }

                    //
                  //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "responseData:"+responsed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "responseData:"+aJson, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    /**
     * Function to display simple Alert Dialog
     * @param context - application context
     * @param title - alert dialog title
     * @param message - alert message
     * @param status - success/failure (used to set icon)
     * */

    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        // Setting alert dialog icon
        alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

**Logout Fragment Code**

If I put any code button any other app crash

```
package com.example.bulksms;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class LogoutFragment extends Fragment {

    //session 
    SessionManager session;
    Context _context;
    public LogoutFragment(){


}
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.logout_fragment, container, false);
     session.logoutUser();
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

**Session Manager class here**

```
package com.example.bulksms;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.util.Log;

public class SessionManager {
    // LogCat tag
    private static String TAG = SessionManager.class.getSimpleName();

    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    Editor editor;
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "BulkSms";

    private static final String KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN = "isLoggedIn";

    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void setLogin(boolean isLoggedIn) {

        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN, isLoggedIn);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();

        Log.d(TAG, "User login session modified!");
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN, false);
    }

    //
    public void setusename(String usename) {
        pref.edit().putString("Username", usename).commit();
        editor.commit();
    }
    //
    public String getusename() {
        String usename = pref.getString("Username","");
        return usename;
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     * */
    public void logoutUser(){
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        _context.getSharedPreferences("BulkSms", 0).edit().clear().commit();
        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }


}
```

**Error LogCat**

```
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503): Process: com.example.bulksms, PID: 28503
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503):    at com.example.bulksms.LogoutFragment.onCreateView(LogoutFragment.java:26)
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:698)
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
12-31 10:40:23.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28503):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: call `session.logoutUser();`  in onCreateView section

Comment: Where are you show LogoutFragment ?

Comment: add session.logoutUser(); in onCreateView but return null pointer exception

Comment: need to call `session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());` before calling `session.logoutUser();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialize your sessionmanager  like this in your fragment...

```
session = new SessionManager(getActivity());
```

it would work...

Answer (score 1):

Simply initialize your `SessionManager` class

```
session = new SessionManager(getActivity());
```

before calling

```
session.logoutUser();
```

Use `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`. Because you'r using fragment.

Comment: Thank's to your valuable answer.